# If I turn off Login requirement am I secure if someone wanted to connect through internet?

Tags: login-screen

I am the only user of PC and use full disk encryption. So I removed login requirement. Is that safe If someone wanted to login remotely while the PC is on?

Comment: W8 is off topic. And you can turn on automatic login with encryption? I thought that was disabled (either autom.login and no encyption or no autom.login and encryption).

Comment: Yes I did it in user account management. And yes it is off topic but what if we were grown ups and help each other instead of picking at little things..

Comment: That would make a mess of Ask Ubuntu. Next you'd want us to help users of (god forbid) Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you are safe. Auto login wont remove the password and it wont stop the authentication it just doesn't ask you for a PW at boot. Firewall(S) very likely also protect you.